# How to replace white space in column? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What I tried?

```
//1    myDataFrame['Gender'] = myDataFrame['Gender'].replace('^\s*$', np.nan)
//2    myDataFrame['Gender'] = myDataFrame['Gender'].replace('', np.nan)
       myDataFrame.to_csv('new_Paymets_Loan.csv')
```

The white space is still the csv file. 
Link to test csv: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eeHGsx3s7nZaSVPCFvtl0Wwp4KJGK8hAlH97n_4DPbI/edit?usp=sharing

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
Gender
Male
Female
Female
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Female

Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Female
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Female
Female
Male
Female
Female
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Female

Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male

Male
Male
Female
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Female
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Female
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male

Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Female
Female
Male
Male
Female
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Female
Male

Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Female
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Female
Male
Male

Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male

Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male

Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male

Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Female
Female
Female
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male

Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
```

Comment: can you share sample input data in copy-pastable format from the csv file

Comment: @ansev - wrongly closed, I think.

Comment: Problem is if write empty values to file it by default write no value.

Comment: I want to change white spaces to NaN on column named Gender

Comment: need `na_rep='NaN'`, default is `na_rep=''` parameter in to_csv

Comment: re.sub('\s','',myDataFrame['Gender'])

Comment: Could you show the csv file **as text**? Excel is known to use fancy displaying...

Comment: @SergeBallesta text is shown in original question as requested.

Comment: @Anshul please see update question.

Comment: @bibscy Can you show, how you are reading the csv file in first place?

Comment: I added na_rep='NaN' and it is finally working.  Please see full code https://gist.github.com/bibscy/28b0c85b61aed478904476dfed08c535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the *string* `NaN` in your **text** csv file. Just put it in the DataFrame:

```
myDataFrame['Gender'] = myDataFrame['Gender'].str.replace('^\s*$', 'NaN')
```

Comment: I did and it is not doing anything. 
```myDataFrame['Gender'] = myDataFrame['Gender'].str.replace('^\s*$', 'NaN')```   
//write to csv      

```myDataFrame.to_csv('new_Paymets_Loan.csv')```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to remove white spaces

```
myDataFrame['Gender'].replace('\s','',inplace=True,regex=True)
```

Comment: error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object